# linuxmint installation error from USB?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, linux-mint

I had made a USB installation using **linuxmint-13-mate-dvd-64bit.iso**. Then I run it inside from windows 7 and intalled it. After when I reboot the linuxmint is a giving an arror like this

```
(initramfs) losetup: could not find any free loop device
```

in the prompt (intramfs) I can type "`help`" command.

But I am not a linux user, so I dont know which should be used ? Please help to me solve this issue ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: try asking on serverfault/superuser

Comment: what is the output of `help`?

Comment: I had copied the installation to harddisk and it works well with installation. @X.Jacobs

Comment: Please answer: (a) Did you start the usb and installed to hard-drive or are trying to boot from the usb-pendrive? (b) In case you installed to hard-drive, did you set the partitions properly (ext4 or as needed) and set mount point as "/" (root)?

Comment: I suggest you start Linux Mint in Live Mode (boot from pendrive) and using the graphical partition tool, gparted, check exactly how your partitions stand. There must be some issue with that if your system is not able to boot up the Linux partition.

Answer (score 0):

The words "USB" and "linux iso" you mentioned lead me to think you did this: you put that iso in the usb flash stick **in a way to make it BOOTABLE** (like a live cd), or, you TRIED to do that.
To make sure you usb flash stick is really bootable, you should really try to boot from usb stick.

Now, this is what (i think) you should do, and what you did.

What you should do, with the bootable usb stick:

- Boot from usb, and click "install on Hard disk" or whatever linux mint has inside it, after succesfully booted the linux SO;

What you did:

- Booted windows and used the files inside usb stick, prepared for "loop mount", to install linux.

Hope this helps.